Error running 'Tomcat 9' Cannot invoke "com.intellij.javaee.appServers.appServers.appServerIntegrations.ApplicationServer.getPersistentData()"
When I start project then I am getting an error:
Error running 'Tomcat 9' 
Cannot invoke "com.intellij.javaee.appServers.appServers.appServerIntegrations.ApplicationServer.getPersistentData()" because the return value of "com.intellij.javaee.appServers.run.configuration.CommonModel.getApllicationServer()" is null


I see it first time - what can cause this issue?
I tried with tomcat 9.0.24 and 9.0.37 and error is the same.
